# Problem with manipulation and plot

Tags: plotting, manipulate

I want to make my function trace the hypotrochoid through one period of its motion and trying to change the color of the trace, color of the radius, and change the color of the dot on it so I can view it easier

I have came up with this following function

```
 hypotrochoid[a_, b_, h_,t_] := {(a - b) Cos[t] + h Cos[(a - b)/b t], (a - b) Sin[t] - 
h Sin[(a - b)/b t]};

 myfigure[a_, b_, h_]:=Manipulate[ParametricPlot[hypotrochoid[a, b, h, t], {t, 0, c*2 \[Pi]},PlotRange -> {{-(a + b + h + 1/4), a + b + h + 1/4}, {-(a + b + h + 1/4), a + b + h + 1/4}}], {c, -1, 1}]
```

Though when I test it on

```
myfigure[5, 1, 1/2]
```

Nothing shows up on this testing.
I know I do not have the coloring but not certain of the syntax require.

Comment: Post complete code. Where's definition for `hypotrochoid`?

Comment: Posted forgot about that

Comment: It works for me. You may want to restart the kernel.

Comment: error message:  ParametricPlot::prng: Value of option PlotRange -> {{-6,6},{{-6},6}} is not All, Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications. >>

Comment: Please restart your *Mathematica* session and try again.

Comment: I did. I closed out, exited program and reopened

Comment: Looks like you might have curly braces {} instead of parentheses () in `PlotRange` (third entry).

Comment: Most recent version of the program.  Ah yes, many thanks.  Would you also happen to know what syntax is used to change the coloring of the trace, radius, and a dot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For coloring try:

```
myfigure[a_, b_, h_] := Manipulate[
  ParametricPlot[
   hypotrochoid[a, b, h, t], {t, 0.0000001, c*2 \[Pi]},
   PlotRange -> {
     {-(a + b + h + 1/4), a + b + h + 1/4},
     {-(a + b + h + 1/4), a + b + h + 1/4}
     },
   PlotStyle -> plotColor,
   Prolog -> {circleColor,
     Circle[{0, 0}, a]},
   Epilog -> {dotColor,
     Disk[hypotrochoid[a, b, h, 2 Pi c ], .2]
     }
   ],
  {c, -1, 1},
  {{plotColor, Red, "Trace"}, Red},
  {{dotColor, Blue, "Dot"}, Blue},
  {{circleColor, Gray, "Circle"}, Gray}
  ]
```

[image: weirdly down-sampled GIF animation]

Comment: very nice...if it is not intrusive, what do you use for screen capture...do you then import into mathematica and convert to animated gif or use other converter?

Comment: @ubpdqn [this one](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1059/61). Sometimes I import them for editing (removing frames from the end or beginning, for example).

Comment: Ah very nice, I'll go play around with that syntax and try some stuff, many thanks.